# Timed tab switching in Bootstrap JS Tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I wanted JS Tabs that would switch according to a preset time and got to the following code:

```
 <script>
  var n=0
  var myVar=setInterval(function () {update_news()}, 1000);

  function update_news() {
    n = n+1
    if (n==4) {
       n=1
    }
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu'+n+'"]').tab('show')

  }
  </script>
```

body:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, as I am not using the links anymore to switch tabs, is there any way I could do it without the `<a href="#menu">` tags? I could just hide it, but I don't find that solution very elegant.

## EDIT:

I actually removed the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute from the links and it wont switch tabs anymore when clicked - but still work with the timer.

That makes me think that the tab switching isn't really related to the link, but just to the existence of the `<a href>` tag in the list under the `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed your `ul` entirely, and I've put a `data-target` attr for each of your `.tab-pane` elements.

```
<div id="menu1" data-target='#menu1' class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu 1</h3>
</div>
```

And then, I've changed your code to:

```
$('#menu'+n).tab('show');
```

Look at the snipped below working:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" data-target='#menu1' class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" data-target='#menu2' class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" data-target='#menu3' class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>  
  var n = 0;
  var myVar = setInterval(update_news, 1000);

  function update_news() {
    n++;
    if (n === 4) n = 1;
    $('#menu'+n).tab('show')
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's way better! I still wonder if we can get rid of the href tags entirely, but I like this solution. If no one comes with a better one, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @SuperGeo it's possible by simulating what Bootstrap does inside its code, but it's not really possible to call `.tab('show')` in any other way, because if you look [inside its code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js#L31), it uses the `href` attribute to perform the operations.

Comment: @SuperGeo Just saw that it looks at a `data-target` attribute before looking at the `href` one. So, if we put a `data-target` attribute on each of the panels, we can then only do `$('#menu'+n).tab('show');`. I've updated my answer!

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `#menu1` directly in JavaScript by changing `location.hash`. This way you don't need `<a>` tags to change it. So for example placing it on a button:

```
<button id="btn1">To Menu1</button>
```

The JavaScript would be:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    location.hash = "#menu1";
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. See my edit concerning the reasons why I think a simple redirection to the hash location wouldn't work.